# Excel VBA Loop through data and copy rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have this software that is set to loop through a dataset and pull rows according to the searchTerm on the specific page. I created two routines to select two different sets of data from the same row and I was hoping to combine them.

```
Public Sub addToMailchimpNameEmail()

    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
    Dim findthisstring As String
    Dim finalrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set datasheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registration Sheet") '<== I have set this up as sheet names not code names
    Set reportsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add to MailChimp")
    findthisstring = reportsheet.Range("H2").Value
    Worksheets("Registration Sheet").Activate

    With datasheet
        finalrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim unionRng As Range

        For i = 2 To finalrow
            If Cells(i, 15) = findthisstring Then '< in column O
                If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 4))) ' 'Select Cols B to D to copy
                Else
                    Set unionRng = .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 4))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

    End With

    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
       If IsEmpty(reportsheet.Range("A150").End(xlUp)) And reportsheet.Range("A150").End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
            unionRng.Copy reportsheet.Range("A1")
        Else
            unionRng.Copy reportsheet.Range("A150").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End If
    Worksheets("Add to MailChimp").Activate
End Sub
```

Here is the second one

```
Public Sub addToMailchimpCityState()

        Dim datasheet As Worksheet
        Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
        Dim findthisstring As String
        Dim finalrow As Long
        Dim i As Long

        Set datasheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registration Sheet") '<== I have set this up as sheet names not code names
        Set reportsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add to MailChimp")
        findthisstring = reportsheet.Range("H2").Value
        Worksheets("Registration Sheet").Activate

        With datasheet
            finalrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Dim unionRng As Range

            For i = 2 To finalrow
                If Cells(i, 15) = findthisstring Then '< in column O
                    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                        Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, .Range(.Cells(i, 9), .Cells(i, 11))) ' 'Select Cols I to K to copy
                    Else
                        Set unionRng = .Range(.Cells(i, 9), .Cells(i, 11))
                    End If
                End If
            Next i

        End With

        If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
           If IsEmpty(reportsheet.Range("A150").End(xlUp)) And reportsheet.Range("A150").End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
                unionRng.Copy reportsheet.Range("A1")
            Else
                unionRng.Copy reportsheet.Range("A150").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3)
            End If
        End If
        Worksheets("Add to MailChimp").Activate
    End Sub
```

The only difference is in the `Set unionRng` sections that I am selecting different columns. I don't have to do a range if someone can tell me how to select col 2,3,4,9,10,11.

Thank you!

Comment: Dropped cells cannot be copied and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a fair combination of your two procedures. It's untested. If it should contain typos please accept my apologies. I think you will be able to correct them.

```
Public Sub addToMailchimpNameEmail()

    Dim Datasheet As Worksheet
    Dim Reportsheet As Worksheet
    Dim Cstart As Long, Cend As Long                ' columns
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim UnionRng As Range
    Dim FindThisString As String
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Datasheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registration Sheet") '<== R have set this up as sheet names not code names
    Set Reportsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add to MailChimp")
    FindThisString = Reportsheet.Range("H2").Value

    Cstart = 2                  ' set columns for first loop
    Cend = 4

    For i = 1 To 2              ' extract different data on each loop
        With Datasheet
            FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For R = 2 To FinalRow
                If Cells(R, 15) = FindThisString Then '< in column O
                    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(R, Cstart), .Cells(R, Cend))
                    If UnionRng Is Nothing Then
                        Set UnionRng = Rng
                    Else
                        Set UnionRng = Union(UnionRng, Rng)
                    End If
                End If
            Next R
        End With

        If Not UnionRng Is Nothing Then         ' How can it ever be Nothing?
            With Reportsheet
                FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                UnionRng.Copy Reportsheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End With
            Set UnionRng = Nothing
        End If

        ' change columns for next loop
        Cstart = 9
        Cend = 11
    Next i

    Worksheets("Add to MailChimp").Activate
End Sub
```

Observe how the columns are set before the first loop and reset at the end of that loop to work for the second loop. This system can't be expanded to work for more than two loops. If such should be your need create arrays (`Dim Cstart As Variant`) before the first loop, like `Cstart = Array(2, 4, 17, 24)` and this use this syntax: `Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(R, Cstart(i)), .Cells(R, Cend(i)))` but remember that `Array()` creates a zero-based array so that you must define your loop as `For i = 0 To Ubound(Cstart)`

Comment: This is great! I will give it a try. Is there a way to set it so I can just pick and choose different columns? I have other sheets to work with that I will have to select a range, then a single column, then another range, etc.

Comment: So I ran this and is half works. It puts in all of Cols 2-4 and then at the bottom of the list it puts in Cols 2-4 again but with Cols 9-11. I am getting a double loop. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it should be this line, `UnionRng.Copy Reportsheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)`. Instead of `Offset(1)` you may want `Offset(1,3)` in the second loop. Declare a variable, say `TargetOffset As Long` and set a value of 3 for it at the end of the first loop. Change the code to `UnionRng.Copy Reportsheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, TargetOffset)`. Your other question is, well, another question. We lack the space and, in fact, also detail of the question itself to deal with it effectively here.

Comment: Thanks Variatus for the idea but that is just moving the second loop's data to the right three columns. The problem is that it runs through the first loop and pastes the first three columns, they runs through the second loop and pastes the first three and second three columns in the correct place. For example, in a sample of 6 rows I end up with the first 6 rows with 3 columns filled out and then another 6 rows with 6 columns filled out. I just want the final set of 6 rows, not the first set with just three columns.

Comment: Yes. That would be an oversight. I have added the line `Set UnionRng = Nothing` to make sure that the result isn't carried from one loop to the next. Sorry about that. It's the curse of not being able to test :-)

Comment: I don't know if I understand. What should I remove. I see  `If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then` but nothing that sets it to nothing.

Comment: That was my omission, exactly. After `If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then` unionRng should become nothing in preparation for the next loop. I added that to my above answer just before the `End If`. It's added, not removed.